# How to select a row which has one coloumn with two different attributes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm doing a project about cooking recipes with PHP(with Codeigniter) and MYSQL.

I have three tables:

- `Ingredients` - `id`, `name`.
- `Recipe` - `id`, `name`
- `ing_to_rep` - `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id` (I use this table for holding which recipe has which ingredients.)

What is the query for "get all recipes which have eggs (`id = 64`) and salt (`id = 65`)"

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM recipe JOIN ing_to_rep ON recipe.id = ing_to_rep.rep_id 
WHERE ing_to_rep.ing_id = 64 AND ing_to_rep.ing_id = 65
```

Naturally, it returns nothing but it helps you to get what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way and a more flexible way, but two subquery joins will do:

```
SELECT
  recipe.*
FROM recipe
  JOIN (SELECT recipe_id FROM ing_to_rep WHERE ingredient_id = 64) AS ing1 ON recipe.id = ing1.recipe_id
  JOIN (SELECT recipe_id FROM ing_to_rep WHERE ingredient_id = 65) AS ing2 ON recipe.id = ing2.recipe_id
```

Also can be done with `EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
  recipe.*
FROM 
  recipe
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT recipe_id FROM ing_to_rep ing1 WHERE ingredient_id = 64 AND recipe.id = ing1.recipe_id)
  AND  EXISTS (SELECT recipe_id FROM ing_to_rep ing2 WHERE ingredient_id = 65 AND recipe.id = ing2.recipe_id)
```

Comment: This solution has a disadvantage: CI (ActiveRecord) doesn't support subqueries! See my subquery-free solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be something like

```
SELECT * FROM recipe r JOIN 
(SELECT recipe_id FROM ing_to_rep 
 GROUP BY recipe_id
 HAVING SUM(IF(ingredient_id IN (64, 65), 1, 0)) = 2) gr ON r.id = gr.recipe_id
```

I am not sure about the performance, you have to try by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery-free method (CI's AR doesn't support subquery):

```
SELECT *
FROM recipe
JOIN ing_to_rep ON (ing_to_rep.id_recipe=recipe.id AND (ing_to_rep.ing_id=64 OR ing_to_rep.ing_id=65))
GROUP BY recipe.id
HAVING COUNT(ing_to_rep.ing_id)=2
```

You can use this solution CI's ActiveRecord.